# How can I display minimum of 8 boxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day, how can I display a minimum of 8 boxes for each row using jQuery?
see below image.

[image: Sample boxes]

each same first letter of ID number should be group into the same boxes.

see code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "API URL HERE",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "token": "TOKEN HERE"
    }
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    if (response) {
      var html = '';
      var data = {};
      var dataNumber;
      for (let data of response) {
        dataNumber = data.AssignmentNumber;
          html = `<div class="bulk"><div class="box">
            <div class="box-assignmentnumber-holder">
              <span id="AssignmentNumber">`+' '+dataNumber+`</span><br/>
            </div>
            <div id="arrow"></div>
            <div class="box-details">
              <div class="bottom-line">
                <label>Region:</label>
                <span>`+' '+data.Region+`</span><br/>
              </div>

              <div class="bottom-line">
                <label>Customer Name:</label>
                <span>`+' '+data.CustomerName+`</span><br/>
              </div>

              <div class="bottom-line">
                <label>Customer Number:</label>
                <span>`+' '+data.CustomerNumber+`</span><br/>
              </div>
              <div class="bottom-line">
                <label>Status:</label>
                <span>`+' '+data.Status+`</span><br/>
              </div>

              <div class="bottom-line">
                <label>Delivery Date:</label>
                <span>`+' '+data.DeliveryDate+`</span><br/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;
        $('.bulks').append(html);
      }

      console.log(response);
      //Select all AssignmentNumber
      var dataNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('body #AssignmentNumber');  
      // loop all AssignmentNumber
      for (var el of dataNumbers) {
        // let AssignmentNumber to array form
        var text = el.textContent;
        text.substring(2);
        //get the first two letter of assignment number 
        var splitNum = text.split("");
        if (splitNum[2] == 1) {
          el.innerHTML = splitNum[1] + '<span style="color: #FF8C00; display: inline-block">' + splitNum[2] + '</span>' + text.substring(3);
        } else {
          el.innerHTML = splitNum[1] + '<span style="color: green; display: inline-block">' + splitNum[2] + '</span>'+ text.substring(3);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  </script>
```

as you can see, only 1 boxes with same first letter of id number is showing. i want them to be group in 1 box since they are having same first letter of id number which is 1.

Comment: what do you mean? reaching to 7?

Comment: sorry, was a stupid comment ... what is your required result, can you show that as I'm having trouble understanding what you want

Comment: i just want to display  11203, 11204 and 11205 into 1 groupbox. as you can see in the first row it only show 1 assignment number.

Comment: oh, a layout issue - so try setting the css for `.box-details { display:inline-block}`